# Can't connect Pyflink source to AWS Kinesis

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, pyflink

I'm using Pyflink and trying to use AWS Kinesis as a source for the Table API using the following instructions:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/python/table/python_table_api_connectors/

Using the connectors here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-sql-connector-kinesis/1.15.0
the code errors even though I have set my region:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For FlinkKinesisConsumer AWS region ('aws.region') and/or AWS endpoint ('aws.endpoint') must be set in the config.`

My code is as follows:

```
from pyflink.table import (EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment, TableDescriptor, Schema,
                           DataTypes, FormatDescriptor)

t_env = TableEnvironment.create(EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode())
t_env.get_config().set("parallelism.default", "1")
t_env.get_config().set("pipeline.jars", "file:///home/ubuntu/connectors/flink-sql-connector-kinesis-1.15.0.jar")
t_env.get_config().set("aws.region", "eu-west-2")


source_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE source_table(
            a VARCHAR,
            b INT
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kinesis',
          'stream' = 'ais_raw',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
          'format' = 'json'
        )
        """

t_env.execute_sql(source_ddl)
t_env.sql_query("SELECT a FROM source_table")
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `aws.region` should be set in the connector options. That is, you need defined the source as following:

```
source_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE source_table(
            a VARCHAR,
            b INT
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'kinesis',
          'stream' = 'ais_raw',
          'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
          'format' = 'json',
          'aws.region' = 'eu-west-2'
        )
        """
```

See [kinesis connector documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/kinesis/#how-to-create-a-kinesis-data-stream-table) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd tried this at the beginning but I must have got something wrong.